# PostgreSQL limiting results by year

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a working PostgreSQL query, column "code" is common in both tables and table test.a has date column and i want to limit search results on year, date format is like ( 2010-08-25 )

```
SELECT *
FROM test.a
WHERE form IN ('xyz')
AND code IN (
SELECT code
FROM test.city)
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: If you have a working query, what is your question?

Comment: `AND datecol BETWEEN DATE '2010-01-01' AND DATE '2010-12-31'`?

Comment: `i want to limit search results on year` leaves room for interpretation. What is your task precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return rows with `date_col` values in the year 2010:

```
SELECT *
FROM   test.a
WHERE  form = 'xyz'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   test.city
   WHERE  code = a.code
   )
AND    date_col >= '2010-01-01'
AND    date_col <  '2011-01-01';
```

This way, the query can use an index on `date_col` (or, ideally on `(form, date_col)` or `(form, code, date_col)` for this particular query). And the filter works correctly for data type `date` and `timestamp` alike (you did not disclose data types, the "date format" is irrelevant).

If performance is of any concern, do not use an expression like <strike>`EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateColumn) = 2010`</strike>. While that seems clean and simple to the human eye it kills performance in a relational DB. The left-hand expression has to be evaluated for *every* row of the table before the filter can be tested. What's more, simple indexes cannot be used. (Only an expression index on `(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateColumn))` would qualify.) Not important for small tables, crucial for big tables.

`EXISTS` can be faster than `IN`, except for simple cases where the query plan ends up being the same. The opposite `NOT IN` can be a trap if NULL values are involved, though:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: well i'm not a professional just tried as i could do best thanks for understanding yap it works perfectly Erwin :)

Answer (score 1):

If by "limit" you mean "filter", then I can give you an option

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  test_a
WHERE
  form IN ('xyz')
  AND code IN (
    SELECT code
    FROM test_city
  )
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dateColumn) = 2010;
```

db-fiddle for you to run and play with it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5ELU6xinJrXiQJ6u6VH5/6